# Bonetrousle | Find B distinct positive integers below K such that their sum is N or say that it is not possible. | Timeout error

Tags: algorithm

I am attempting the [Bonetrousle HackerRank challenge.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bonetrousle/problem)

The problem is the following:

*Find B distinct positive integers below K such that their sum is N or say that it is not possible.*

**Constraints:**

```
n, k <= 10^18
b <= 10^5
```

You can check that a solution exists if the given N lies between the minimum(take first B elements) and maximum(take last B elements) possible sum.
From there on, I start with the minimum sum, and try to make it to N by assigning each element the maximum possible value without breaking the constraint. (no duplication, sum == N)

Below is the code I wrote.

```
def foo1(n,k,b):
    minSum = (b*(b+1))//2
    maxSum = (b)*(k-b+1+k)//2
    #maxSum = (k*(k+1))//2 - minSum
    #print(minSum, maxSum)


    if n>=minSum and n<=maxSum:
        minArr = [i for i in range(1,b+1)]
        minArr.reverse()
        sumA = sum(minArr)

        maxA = k
        for i in range(len(minArr)):
            tmp = minArr[i]
            minArr[i] = maxA
            sumA = sumA-tmp+minArr[i]

            while sumA > n:
                sumA -=1
                minArr[i] -= 1
            maxA = minArr[i]-1
            """
            while sumA+1 <= n and minArr[i]+1 <= k and minArr[i]+1 != maxA:
                #print(minArr, maxA)

                minArr[i]+=1
                sumA +=1
            maxA = minArr[i]    
            if sumA == n:
                break
            """

    else:
        return [-1]
    return minArr
```

The code outputs correct solutions however it times out on hacker rank for 4 test cases. (sample n,b,k : 19999651, 20000000, 6324)
It gives answer within 3 seconds on my machine for the same test case.

Initially I thought the issue was with the commented code, since I was trying to increment each element array 1-by-1 until the sum was reached. I modified the code to assign each element the maximum possible value and then decrement it if it breaks the constraints, however it did not help much, apparently.

Any suggestion on modifying the code to get it to pass the timing constraint or a much faster algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find the **B** largest *consecutive* integers with sum <= **N**.  The problem is impossible if this sequence starts at an integer < 1 or ends at an integer > **K**

The sum of **B** integers starting at **x** is **B*(2x+B-1)/2**, so just solve for **x** directly.

Obviously, if you were to add one to each of the integers in the sequence starting at **x**, then you'd get the *next* **B** consecutive integers, and their sum is > **N**, so you don't need to increment that many.  Just add 1 to the highest **N-sum** integers in the sequence to make the sum come out right.

Comment: Any proof for `N - max_sum <= B`?

Comment: @PhamTrung If **N - sum >= B**, then you should have chosen a larger **x**.